# vnstat does not show today statistics in conky

Tags: conky, vnstat

I am using Xubuntu 15.10. My conky does not show the Today statistics anymore.  Command `vnstat` in a terminal produces unreadable characters under day column. Month total is shown. My relevant `conky.rc` lines are:

```
${color0}Today: ${goto 60}${color3}${execi 60 vnstat | grep "today" | awk '{print $2 $3}'}  ${goto 165}${color4}${execi 60 vnstat | grep "today" | awk '{print $5 $6}'}  
${color0}${font Ubuntu Condensed:bold:size=11}Month: ${goto 60}${color1}${execi 60 vnstat -m | grep "`date +"%b '%y"`" | awk '{print $3 $4}'} ${goto 165}${execi 60 vnstat -m | grep "`date +"%b '%y"`" | awk '{print $6 $7}'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in another forum.  The date characters was not rendered properly in the vnstat command.  'LC_ALL=C vnstat' command produced correct output in the terminal, so I added 'LC_ALL=C' before the 'vnstat' command in my conky.rc file in the Today line, and now it is giving proper figures.
The vnstat.conf file already shows 'Locale "-"'.  I do not know why it has to be mentioned again.
However since the problem is solved, the question may be treated a solved.

```
NETWORK:  ${alignr}(${addr eth0})
```

DOWN: ${color1}${downspeed eth0} ${goto 135}${color0}UP: ${color1}${upspeed eth0} ${color0}
${downspeedgraph eth0 25,113 ff0000 ffff00 -t -l} ${alignr}${upspeedgraph eth0 25,113 66ffff 6600ff -l -t}
${color0}Total: ${goto 60}${color3}${totaldown eth0} ${goto 165}${color4}${totalup eth0}
${color0}Today: ${goto 60}${color3}${execi 60 LC_ALL=C vnstat | grep "today" | awk '{print $2 $3}'}  ${goto 165}${color4}${execi 60 LC_ALL=C vnstat | grep "today" | awk '{print $5 $6}'}

Comment: can you edit this answer to show the corrected script?